# Cannot exit app with ionic2 on iOS? Is there a way to exit app?

Tags: ios, angular, react-native, flutter, ionic2

I've build an Ionic2 app and using

```
this.platform.exitApp()
```

in app.component.ts to exit app.

On Android it's work well, but got this error on iOS

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.navigator.app.exitApp')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the iPhone there is no concept of quitting an app. The only action that should cause an app to quit is pressing the Home button on the phone, and that's not something developers have access to.

According to Apple, your app should not terminate on its own. Please check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1561/_index.html) link

Comment: @sebaferreras sure :)

Comment: So can you send a 'Home' event somehow? And if you can why isn't the relevant Cordova plugin doing that?

Comment: @JGFMK No. We cant do a home event programatically. apple will not accept any such things